# Virtual keyboard Popup not working on a derived textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, keyboard, popup, virtual

I have a derived class called NumericTextBox that is derived from TextBox.This has all the validationsf for the data to be numeric. Now, i have a popup attached to this textbox in my window. the popup is a virtual keyboard. this lets the user input from both Keyboard and Mouse. but whenever i click a button on the popup, the PreivewTextInput is not getting fired. i raise the keybd_event. Please suggest a solution to this
Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to observe/monitor the events that fire when your application is running.